# Laravel/PHP variables in same functions are somehow tied to session?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What is happening here, I have laravel code :

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->test();
    }

    public function index2()
    {
        $this->test();
    }

    private function test(){
        $milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
        \DB::transaction(function (){
            $order = Order::find(1)->lockForUpdate()->first();
            $order->update(['session_id' => str_random(40)]);
            sleep(2);
        });
        $milliseconds2 = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
        echo 'milliseconds=' . ($milliseconds2 - $milliseconds) . ' ms';
    }
}
```

when I run index route in two tabs in browser results is:

```
first tab  : milliseconds=2068 ms
second tab : milliseconds=2065 ms
```

although one request takes about 2 seconds, another 4 seconds

when I run index route in one tab, index2 in second tab result is something like:

```
first tab  : milliseconds=2082 ms
second tab : milliseconds=4117 ms
```

also one request takes about 2 seconds, another 4 seconds.
This is very strange, what is going on here ?!??

Comment: What web server are yous using?

Comment: homestead - Nginx

Comment: well, hmm, a php sleep() inside a DB transaction with an update lock, are you searching for weird thinks or does this have a meaning for you?

Comment: I am testing locking and and I run on this issue...

Comment: imho a php sleep() inside a transaction with a lock is searching for weird thinks. If you want to test transaction give the database a lot of records to update and remove the php sleep().

Comment: "do not use sleep inside transaction" is not solution to this problem. There must be explanation why this is happening...